# PHP string to be used in onclick

Tags: javascript, php, string

I need to properly escape a PHP string so that it can be used as a string parameter in onclick.

My string is stored in `$x` and it may contain single quote ('), double quote ("), ampersand (&) and backslash(\).

I think this code is necessary and sufficient:

```
<a onclick="alert('<?= str_replace(array("\\", "'"), array("\\\\",'\x27'), htmlspecialchars($x)) ?>')" href="#">Click here</a>
```

The `htmlspecialchars` function takes care of double quote and ampersand. The `str_replace` takes care of single quote and backslash. (I tried using ENT_QUOTES in `htmlspecialchars`, but that is not enough in this case.)

Can this be simplified?
Am I missing something?

Comment: You may find it easier to separate the logic of 2 different languages.  At least echo the strings to javascript variables.  Writing multiple languages on the same line will drain your soul.

Comment: _“I tried using ENT_QUOTES in htmlspecialchars, but that is not enough in this case.”_ – of course it is not, because that escapes the data for a completely different _context_ – for the context _HTML_.

Comment: Maybe PHP Filter can offer you help: https://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php - but they have some flaws. Read the comments to get more infos about them. Otherwise and maybe a better solution is preg_replace: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Flosculus, I think your comment is the most useful here. If you turn it into an answer, I will accept it as an answer to my question.